# Different __hash__ and __eq__ methods for use in set

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, set

I'm trying to implement a set-based solution for a problem and have been running into some issues.

The problem is: I have 2 sets of `Group` objects. These sets should be unique on `email` (so we can check if an object from one set is `in` the other set).

However, two `Group` objects are not `__eq__()` if they only have an email match (for example, one set may contain an updated `Group` object that has a new `description`). The goal is to have a set where I can perform set operations (intersection and difference) based only on the `email` field... then check equality based on other fields (`description` and `name`)

```
    class Group:
        def __init__(self, name, email, description):
            self.name = name
            self.email = email
            self.description = description

        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.email)

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.email == other.email 
                    and self.description == other.description 
                    and self.name == other.name

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not self.__eq__(other)

        def __str__(self):
            return "Description: {0} Email: {1} Name: {2}".format(self.description, self.email, self.name)
```

So i'd expect all assert statements to pass here:

```
    group_1 = Group('first test group', 'testing@example.com', 'example description')
    group_2 = Group('second test group', 'real@example.com', 'example description')
    group_3 = Group('third group', 'testing@example.com', 'example description')
    group_5 = Group('updated name', 'testing@example.com', 'example description')

    group_set = set([group_1, group_2, group_3])
    group_set_2 = set([group_3, group_5])

    self.assertTrue(group_5 in group_set.intersection(group_set_2))
    self.assertEqual(2, len(group_set))
    self.assertTrue(group_5 in group_set)
```

Comment: for sets the `__eq__` and `__hash__` *must* be based on the same information. You cannot have an `__eq__` use 3 fields and `__hash__` only use the email.

Comment: Why are you not just using email in eq?

Comment: You can't do that.  What you might try is creating some sort of "email" object that has a reference to its group, then make a set of email objects that allows you to get from its members to their groups.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Thanks @Martijn !  @ Padraic groups are not equal if only their emails are equal. But email should be treated as a unique key. @ BrenBarn: thanks for the suggestion! I'll think on what the most elegant solution to this would be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The requirement is only that `x == y` implies `hash(x) == hash(y)`. This implementation is fine, albeit not useful

Comment: @Eric: yes, that's more what I meant to say; but having the hash be the same based only on the email address means you'll increase the number of collisions where objects with the same email address all hash to the same slot but are not considered equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `set` type uses the equality test implemented by an object's `__eq__` method to determine if an object is "the same" as another object in its contents. The `__hash__` method only allows it to find other elements to compare against more efficiently. So, your hope of using a `__hash__` method based on a different set of attribute than the `__eq__` method will not work. Multiple unequal objects with the same `__hash__` value can exist in the same `set` (though the `set` will be somewhat less efficient due to the hash collisions).

If you want a unique mapping from an email address to a `Group`, I suggest using a dictionary where the keys are email addresses and the values are `Group` objects. This will let you ensure the email addresses are unique, while also letting you compare `Group` objects in whatever way is most appropriate.

To perform a union between two such dictionaries, use the `update` method on a copy of one dictionary:

```
union = dict_1.copy()
union.update(dict_2)
```

For an intersection, use a dictionary comprehension:

```
intersection = {email: group for email, group in dict_2.iteritems() if email in dict_1}
```

Both of those operations will prefer the values from `dict_2` over the values from `dict_1` wherever the same email occurs as a key in both. If you want it to work the other way, just switch the dictionary names around.